# CSS Grid powered table with scrollable tbody and auto-width on columns

Tags: css, css-tables, css-grid

I read other posts on SO about the matter but before you all start yelling at me `just use tables for tabular data!` let me say that this is an attempt to solve specific `<table/>` problems:

- having a scrollable tbody: mandatory for big data and virtual scrolling
- have the thead columns and tbody columns auto-adjust with the best fit based on the cell contents (not all equally-wide and without manually specifying width on each of them): which you now loose once you declare `display:block` the tbody

I was trying to leverage the `display:contents` or `display:subgrid` (ff and chrome with experimental flags enabled) for this.

**Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?**

In my attempt I'm posting here:

- I'm loosing the chance to set an height on my tbody because of the `display:contents` which let the children behave direct children of the container parent (table)
- I'm not sure whether I can nest `display:contents` elements

Here the snippet: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ppWwKv

Other references:

- [Create a Table with CSS grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873687/create-a-table-with-css-grid)
- [CSS Grid / Table Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123666/css-grid-table-question)

Comment: I’m not going to yell at you, but you should absolutely leave tabular data in tables, and start by reading Richard Rutter on readability of tables https://alistapart.com/article/web-typography-tables and these design patterns by Andrew Coyle.

Comment: @denmch thanks for the link, I totally agree with all being said. But I don't see the point: what we are talking about here, is having the same "table visual features" but with a more flexible "code" structure. Data is always tabular. But as I stated, a scrollable tbody is indeed mandatory for virtual list capabilities and having columns auto-fitting the content would be desired as well. You can't have this now with <table/> but maybe you can with <div[display:grid] />. The way you're going to style them is your business, and I agree with you and the article guidelines on that.

Comment: Why can't you have that with a table that's semantically a table? This whole line of thinking makes me sad.

Comment: @denmch!!! once again ==> ```scrollable tbody is indeed mandatory for virtual list capabilities and having columns auto-fitting the content would be desired as well```